# Foreign Key Reference Already Has Value Exception Linq to SQL When Assigning Null

Tags: c#, sql, linq

In the case where a foreign key already has a reference but I want to remove that reference how would I do that?

```
queryRecord.Single().OrderID = null;
```

Throws this ForeignKeyReferenceAlreadyHasValueException, I realize you have to set it to an entity, but how can I set it to a null entity?

I tried

```
Order nullOrder = new Order();
queryRecord.Single().Orders = nullOrder.OrderID;
```

but that also throws the same ForeignKeyReferenceAlreadyHasValueException

So how do I null that field?

Comment: Yes, that appears to work.  Didn't realize I had to set the entity to null.  Submit that as an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to do:

```
queryRecord.Single().Orders = null;
```

As much as I remember, you have to **set the association property to null** to remove or change foreign key association.